# Ubuntu 13.04 random crashes

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, kernel, google-chrome, system

I'm having a problem which seems to get worse as time goes on.

I'm having random crashes (image links at the bottom), It used to happen about once a week or so, but now it happens a few times a day. I had this one 12.04, and hoped that upgrading To 13.04 would solve it, but after a few months with 13.04, it's still happening.

Sometimes it's general protection fault, sometimes page fault, sometimes, something else, And it's on different processes too. Mostly chrome, but not just.

I ran MemoryTest for the night but that didn't seems to do anything.

Images:

- [Chrome crash](http://i42.tinypic.com/w7j7r8.jpg)
- [update-apt-xapl crash](http://i42.tinypic.com/2rqjez7.jpg)

System info:

Lenovo B570, Intel i3-2310 @ 2.10 GHz 64 bit, 8GB RAM

OS is 13.04 64bit

**EDIT**

Something I forgot to mention, and might be important. My machine is dual-boot with Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

Even though I hardly ever log in to my Windows OS, maybe once a month if at all, I didn't seem to have any crashes or anything inside Windows

Any suggestions? I don't want to format my computer if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like overheated or faulty hardware. Could be the CPU or RAM. Is your machine excessively hot at any place, when the crashes occur?

#### Test RAM

Install memtest86+, reboot and run it from the grub boot menu. One pass should be enough.

#### Test CPU

This one's more difficult, because there's no good CPU stress test in the repositories. A simple one would be to run this for a few hours:

```
sudo apt-get install stress
stress -c `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`
```

#### Check package integrity

Another possible reason is a corrupted commonly used shared library (think libc). You can check their integrity with [debsums](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/distro/debian/deb16-PackageRelatedCommandsIntegrityCheck/).

Comment: I installed and ran the memtest86+, gave it a whole night. As for the temp, no, it doesn't seem to be hotter when it crashes, it doesn't get really hot at all. I'll run the cpu test you suggested. Thanks for your reply

Comment: it ran for 5 hours and nothing happened

Comment: And a few minutes after starting using it, it crashes again this time with `iwconfig` process. and one it boot up, crashed again. Any chance formatting would help? or this seems to be a hardware issue?

Comment: I described another test for package integrity in my answer.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your help. I ran that test, and almost all were OK except a few. Here's the pastebin link  with the failed ones http://pastebin.com/s2qKWHe8. Does that help?

Comment: I've also added a small edit to my question with some dual-boot information

Comment: Could also be a faulty driver (or a driver that trips a faulty device firmware). Try do disable as much hardware (drivers) as possible and see, if that stabilises your machine. Then turn them on one by one and check again.